# Отслеживание наведение курсора на полигон OpenGL

Tags: windows, c++, opengl

На OpenGL сцену вывел 9 квадратов. Как отследить и подсветить квадрат, если на него наведён курсор мыши?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно средствами OpenGL. Посмотреть как можно [здесь](http://www.gamedev.ru/articles/?id=20118)

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, моя идея будет весьма неадекватной по отношению к OpenGL, но иного решения я не нашел. Попробуйте брать цвет пикселя в текущем положениии курсора функцией `glReadPixels`.
Если цвет отличный от цвета используемого в `glClearColor`, то это квадрат.

Comment: Мыслите правильно, но нужно оперировать не цветами пикселей, а конвертировать координаты курсора из `Projection Space` в `World Space`, а после этого производить `Hit Test` с объектами в нем.

Comment: Ну это уже совсем другой подход =)